# Xamarin CarouselPage not showing if not master page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I've inherited a Xamarin project and am not sure why I'm seeing this behavior when trying to work with a CarouselPage.

Using the Prism NavigationService, if I navigate to the carousel page as the "base page", it shows fine, but if I navigate to it as a "sub page" (to push it on the navigation stack?) it doesn't show, though I get no errors.

The problem is that using the navigation method that works doesn't provide me with a back button.

Example:

```
// this works, but no back button
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("file:///MenuMasterDetailPage/MenuNavigationPage/MyCarouselPage");

// this doesn't, have back button but no content is shown
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MyCarouselPage");
```

I'm unsure how the master/detail/navigation stuff really works: not sure if my issue is there or if there's something special about a CarouselPage that prevents it from being rendered in the second case.

The MyCarouselPage is as simple as can be while I try to get this to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             x:Class="Views.ImageCarouselPage"
            effects:BackgroundImageEffect.BackgroundImage="Resources.SignInBackground.png">

    <ContentPage>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="https://s3.amazonaws.com/blah.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="https://s3.amazonaws.com/blah.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

</CarouselPage>
```

(I should note that the background image does display, but the contents of the carousel does not).

Any ideas?  Thanks.